# Woocommerce attributes custom order with multiple pages

Tags: woocommerce

Drag and drop Custom ordering is great. But how can I adjust the order when I have 2 or more pages of attributes? Can I have attribute page display more than 20 attributes so I could see them all at once and drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did not realize I can increase the number of items per page with screen options.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxncc.jpg)